# SimpleAction Error Message

Tags: ros, actionlib, simpleactionclient

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I got this message: BUG: Got a transition to CommState [PENDING] when our in SimpleGoalState [ACTIVE]

This seems to be printed in the simple_action_client.h when the client receives a state different that what it expects. How is this possible? What did I do wrong?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10370/simpleaction-error-message/) by [miltos](https://answers.ros.org/users/559/miltos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2011-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on 2011-06-24**:
Also remember to mention what version of the common stack you're using.  There were some bugfixes to the client state matchine in 1.4.4.

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2011-06-24**:
Can you provide a small sample program that reproduces this problem? This will help us with debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0